# Android setVisibility from invisible to visible not working

Tags: android

I am new to Android development, I have a problem of trying to set a imageview's visibility invisible or visible with a button, it works when the visibility is going from visible to invisible, but it doesn't work when trying to set from invisible back to visible, here's my code:

XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/diagram_img"
    android:id="@+id/ImgDiagram"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/ViewInput1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/ViewInput2" />
```

visibility function:

```
 if (id == R.id.action_diagram) {
        if(triangleDiagram.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
            triangleDiagram.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if(triangleDiagram.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            triangleDiagram.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be an else-if statement. Why? If you have two ifs, the first one changes the state to visible, and the other ones condition is met (visible), so the invisible code is executing

```
 if (id == R.id.action_diagram) {
        if(triangleDiagram.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
            triangleDiagram.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else if(triangleDiagram.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            triangleDiagram.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

You know, if the diagram is invisible (**Wrong** code below):

```
    if(triangleDiagram.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) { // evaluates to true
        triangleDiagram.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // changes to visible
    }
    if(triangleDiagram.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) { // diagram is visible so evaluates to true
        triangleDiagram.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // diagram is going invisible
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (id == R.id.action_diagram) {
        if(triangleDiagram.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
            triangleDiagram.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if(triangleDiagram.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            triangleDiagram.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

to

```
if (id == R.id.action_diagram) {
    if(triangleDiagram.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
        triangleDiagram.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if(triangleDiagram.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        triangleDiagram.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    return true;
}
```

as the problem with your code was that the view is set to visible and then it executes the next if loop in which, the view is again made invisible.